# How to find the special symbol in String by void equals in Java

Tags: java, char

In the String s  "Jack's", I want to use `charAt(4) equals ' ' '` to get the special symbol `'`. 
And `'` can't be found.

like `char s = ' ' ';`

How can I define the special symbol `'`?

Comment: *"And ' can't be found."* How are you searching? Can you please [edit] your question to include your code? (Please see [mcve])

Comment: Are you just asking how to represent the apostrophe character?  ```'\''```  -- the whole thing is enclosed in apostrophes, and the actual apostrophe is preceded by backslash which "escapes" the usual meaning of marking the end of the character constant.

Comment: What do you mean by 'void equals'?

Answer (score 0):

String s = "Jack's";
char a = s.charAt(4);

System.out.println(a); //print '

Comment: Not this, I just want to ensure whether the symbol here is ' . for example , i can use charAt(i)equals('+') to ensure the symbol here is +. But i can't use this to equals ' .